# Стриминг в Youtube через GStreamer

Tags: youtube, gstreamer

Пытаюсь слать видеотрансляцию на youtube. В качестве теста создаю на youtube канале трансляцию, получаю нужный url и ключ трансляции, затем создаю например вот такой pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=1 ! videoconvert ! "video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, 
framerate=60/1" ! queue ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! "video/x-h264,profile=main" ! flvmux streamable=true 
name=mux ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/x/0cqu-tet8-fjz4-5daa-40av app=live2
```

судя по gst-debug, pipeline корректно создается, однако далее ничего не происходит, трансляция не подхватывается и gst-launch завершает выполнение через несколько секунд без каких-либо ошибок.
подскажите, что я делаю не так?

UPD: попробовал со звуковой дорожкой, результат тот же:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=1 ! videoconvert ! "video/x-raw, 
width=1280, height=720, framerate=25/1" ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=2000 byte-
stream=false key-int-max=60 bframes=0 aud=true tune=zerolatency ! "video/x-
h264,profile=main" ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux ! rtmpsink 
location="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/x/$6e2w-m9pq-zgm3-jc6m-5kse 
app=live2" audiotestsrc ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! mux.
```

Comment: Насчёт завершения не знаю, но из своих экспериментов знаю, что ютуб обязательно требует наличия звука. Пусть даже это будет аудиодорожка с полной тишиной, но она должна быть

Comment: А ещё у вас rtmpsink location слишком странный, должно хватить простого `location="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/6e2w-m9pq-zgm3-jc6m-5kse"` без всяких долларов, иксов и аппов

Comment: По крайней мере с нормальным location у меня стрим пошёл https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDjF7Trsm1o

Comment: @andreymal а можете показать какой пайплайн вы используете?

Comment: Ваш из вопроса и скопировал

Comment: @andreymal, я видимо в упор чего-то не вижу, можете пожалуйста оформить ответ и туда вписать корректный пайп. вы через консоль на винде пускаете? и когда создавали трасляцию, у вас default stream key стоял? т.е не битрейт, ничего дополнительного вы не настраивали?

Comment: Команда ничем не отличается от вашей, кроме правильно прописанного location

Comment: @andreymal, все никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Можете, пожалуйста, сообщить на какой ос и с какой версией gstreamer вы запускали pipeline. Попробую продублировать...

Comment: @andreymal, м-да, попробовал на чистой машине - заработало. Спасибо вам. Оформите ответ, я зачту.